# Calculating number of possibilities where difference between the number next to the n and the n does not exceed 3

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm in the process of creating a program to school and I encountered a problem in one of the parts of my job.

n - this is the amount of numbers

My program needs to calculate number of possibilities where difference between the number next to the n and the n does not exceed 3.

**And sometimes one defined number can't stand next to the other.**

For example:
n=3
result=2, because:

```
312 (abs(3-1)<=3; abs(1-2)<=3; abs(2-3)<=3;)
321 (abs(3-2)<=3; abs(2-1)<=3; abs(1-3)<=3;)
```

n=5
result=12, because:

```
52134 (abs(5-2)<=3; abs(2-1)<=3; abs(1-3)<=3; abs(3-4)<=3; abs(4-5)<=3;)
52143 (etc.)
52314
52413
53124
53142
53214
53412
54123
54132
54213
54312
```

n=4
result=6, because:

```
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
```

**n=5 and 3 can't stand on the right of 5 and 2 can't stand on the right of 1**
result=6, because:

```
52134
52143
52314
52413
54132
54213
```

I have an idea to start from putting numbers on the left and on the right of n.
For example:

```
5
453
24531 => 53124 and 54213

23541 => 54123 and 53214

32541 => 54132 and 52314
etc.
```

But I can't imagine how this algorithm (recursive perhaps?) step by step should look like.
Could you help me?

Sorry for my bad English, if anything is unclear, please ask.
Defozo

Comment: Are you limited to natural numbers? Otherwise the number is infinite

Comment: One very dumb solution would be trying all the numbers that have n digits (in a for loop) and check that it respects your conditions.

Comment: @Ed Heal Yes, I forgot to add that I'm limited to natural numbers.

Comment: @VAndrei I wish it was more effective.

Comment: Is not the answer in mathematics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: @EdHeal You have to bear in mind that sometimes one defined number can't stand next to the other so I think it can't be just mathematics.